# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in mern stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, mern, connection-refused

Im a beginner and Im building a simple react app  but my data is not getting sent to the database, the error is axios error : network error in console the error is net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, ive been struggling for 2 weeks please help. im using mern technology im using port 3000 and 8071 for backend. I connected my backend with postman and it works correctly after coding the frontent, Im facing this problem. I tried changing the port, I disabled my firewall and i tried dns flush and alot more options nothing works.

supplier.js in routes

```
let Supplier = require("../models/Supplier");

router.route("/add").post((req,res)=>{
    
    const name = req.body.name;
    const address = req.body.address;
    const contactNumber = req.body.contactNumber;
    const email = req.body.email;

    const newSupplier = new Supplier({
        name,
        address,
        contactNumber,
        email

    })

     newSupplier.save().then(()=>{
        res.json("Supplier Added")
     }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
     })
     
})

router.route("/").get((req,res)=>{
    Supplier.find().then((suppliers)=>{
        res.json(suppliers)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })

})

router.route("/update/:id").put(async (req,res) => {
    let supplierId = req.params.id;
    const {name, address, contactNumber, email} = req.body;

    const updateSupplier = {
        name,
        address,
        contactNumber,
        email
    }
    

    const update = await Supplier.findByIdAndUpdate(supplierId, updateSupplier)
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).send({status: "Supplier updated"})
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send({status: "Error with updating data", error: err.message});
    })
})

router.route("/delete/:id").delete(async (req,res) => {
    let supplierId = req.params.id;

    await Supplier.findByIdAndDelete(supplierId)
    .then(() => {
        res.status(200).send({status: "Supplier Deleted"});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).send({status: "error with deleting Supplier", error: err.message});
    })
})

router.route("/get/:id").get(async (req, res) => {
    let supplierId = req.params.id;

    const supplier = await Supplier.findById(supplierId)
    .then((supplier) => {
        res.status(200).send({status: "Supplier fetched", supplier})
    }).catch(() => {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500).send({status: "Error with get user", error: err.message});

    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

AddSupplier.js

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import AdminDashBoard from "./AdminDashBoard";
import Header from "./Header";
import AdminSideBar from "./AdminSidebar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import axios from "axios";
import styles from "./assets/css/styles.css";

export default function AddSupplier(){

    const [supplierName, setSupplierName] = useState("");
    const [address, setAddress] = useState("");
    const [contactNumber, setContactNumber] = useState("");
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

    function sendData(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const newSupplier = {
            supplierName,
            address,
            contactNumber,
            email
        }
        
        axios.post("http://localhost:8071/supplier/add", newSupplier).then(()=>{
            alert("Supplier Added")
        }).catch((err)=> {
            alert(err)
        })

    }

    return(
        <div >
            <Header></Header>

        <div className="containerf">
            <AdminSideBar></AdminSideBar>

        <div className="container" >
        
            <form onSubmit={sendData}>
                <h3>Add Supplier Details</h3>
  <div className="form-group">
    <label for="supplierName">Supplier Name</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="supplierName"  placeholder="Enter Supplier Name" 

    onChange={(e)=>{
        setSupplierName(e.target.value);
    }} />
   
  </div>
  <div className="form-group">
  <label for="address">Supplier Address</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="address"  placeholder="Enter Supplier Address"
    
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setAddress(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>
 
  <div className="form-group">
  <label for="contactNumber">Contact Number</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="contactNumber"  placeholder="Enter Contact Number"
    
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setContactNumber(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>

  <div className="form-group">
  <label for="email">Supplier email</label>
    <input type="text" className="form-control" id="email"  placeholder="Enter Supplier email"
    
    onChange={(e)=>{
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    }} />
  </div>


  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Insert Data</button>
</form>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <Footer></Footer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Server.js in backend folder

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

const app = express(); 
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8071;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());



const URL = process.env.MONGODB_URL;

mongoose.connect(URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
});

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once("open", () => {
    console.log("Mongodb Connection success!");
})

const supplierRouter = require("./routes/suppliers.js");

app.use("/supplier", supplierRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up and running on port:  ${PORT}`)
})
```